# Can not find a date pattern

Tags: date, time, solr, iso8601

Can't find a pattern for this date. Could anyone help me?
I know it's ISO 8601 standart.But everything I have found was without `:` between `03` and `00`.

```
2018-01-18T08:40:00+03:00
```

How do I can parse this to `Thu Jan 18 00:00:00 GMT+03:00 2018` to this `2018-01-18T08:40:00+03:00`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  It's especially hard when you don't even tag for the language you're using. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this **W3C Datetime** format is typically used for < lastmod >  timestamps in XML.
[related & more detailed answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349345/how-to-properly-format-last-modified-lastmod-time-for-xml-sitemaps)